# Use ArrayList to store information and to access the information

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have to create a program which allows a user to entry information that includes a name,address,city,state,zip code,and age. A data structure ArrayList will be used to store information. Create classes to create objects and the classes methods to access information.

1. create a class called GroupArrayProject which will contain the main method.
2. You will create a class called People use ArrayList for name,address, city,state, zip, and age variables.
3. Create a method called AddRecord
4. AddRecord will be the method called to add records and its purpose is to call other methods that will be used.
5. These other methods(ex. addName()) will be called and used to enter the information for each ArrayList named above.
6. create a menu that allow for the program to:

a. show all the records you have entered

b. to show oldest or youngest

c. to find a record using first name or last name.

```
public class people {
 String name, address, city, state, zipcode, age;

 public people() {
  name = null;
  address = null;
  city = null;
  state = null;
  zipcode = null;
  age = null;
 }
 public void setpeople(String n, String ad, String c, String s, String z, String a) {
  name = n;
  address = ad;
  city = c;
  state = s;
  zipcode = z;
  age = a;
 }
 public string AddRecord
 public String getpeople() {
  String p = "name:" + name + "\n" + "address:" + address + "\n" + "city:" + city + "\n" + "state:" + state + "\n" + "zip code:" + zipcode + "\n" + "age:" + age;
  return p;
 }
}

public class GroupArrayProject {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  {
   ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
   people two = new people();
   Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("type in your name,address,city,state,zipcode and age ");
   String a = one.next();
   String b = one.next();
   String c = one.next();
   String d = one.next();
   String e = one.next();
   String f = one.next();
   two.setpeople(a, b, c, d, e, f);
   System.out.println(two.getpeople());

  }
 }
}
```

That's what I've so far, I don't really know what to do next

Comment: maybe use proper names for variables, classes and methods first? just an idea.. and then what`s your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

rename your People class to Person

zipcode and age should be integers not Strings

create another constructor in the Person class with parameters that you will use to initialize your instance data

add getter and setter methods for each instance variable in the class.

add the following to the GroupArrayProject class:

private static List people = new ArrayList<>();

addRecord() should be in the GroupArrayProject class.

```
public void addRecord(Scanner input){
    System.out.println("Name");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("Address");

    ...

    people.add(new Person(...));
}
```

That's the basics. You just need to create methods to search through your list of people and find matches and then your done.